# Using Socket.IO in NodeJS works local, but not on Heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, websocket, socket.io

Im traying to create a NodeJs Server for android clients. When i run the server local it works perfect! But when i try to host the server in Heroku, it does not work. I get a Application Error "An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details. You can do this from the Heroku CLI with the command".
when i take the line <> out from index.js, it works also on Heroku.

In the logs i get a H10 error: 
2019-07-05T04:09:20.917720+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" ....

2019-07-05T04:09:21.119408+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" ....

What is the problem ? Many thanks!

**Index.js**

```
const express = require('express');
app = express(),
    http = require('http'),
    server = http.createServer(app);

    // without this line it works also on Heroku
    io = require('socket.io').listen(server); 

const path = require('path')
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000

express()
    .use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))
    .set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'))
    .set('view engine', 'ejs')
    .get('/', (req, res) => res.render('pages/index'))
    .listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Listening on ${ PORT }`))
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "node-js-getting-started",
  "version": "0.3.0",
  "description": "A sample Node.js app using Express 4",
  "engines": {
    "node": "10.x"
  },
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js",
    "test": "node test.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "ejs": "^2.5.6",
    "express": "^4.15.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "request": "^2.81.0",
    "tape": "^4.7.0"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/heroku/node-js-getting-started"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "node",
    "heroku",
    "express"
  ],
  "license": "MIT"
}
```

**app.json**

```
{
  "name": "Start on Heroku: Node.js",
  "description": "A barebones Node.js app using Express 4",
  "repository": "https://github.com/heroku/node-js-getting-started",
  "logo": "https://cdn.rawgit.com/heroku/node-js-getting-started/master/public/node.svg",
  "keywords": ["node", "express", "heroku"],
  "image": "heroku/nodejs"
}
```

**gitignore**

```
# Node build artifacts
node_modules
npm-debug.log

# Local development
*.env
*.dev
.DS_Store

# Docker
Dockerfile
docker-compose.yml
```

Answer (score 0):

What about add socket.io to package.json as dependencies?

Comment: ya that was my problem! Thanks!